# How to reload Application Class in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I noticed that my configuration which was parsed from a yml file is not being reloaded when I start up a console. Here is my application.rb file:

```
module MyApp

  def self.config

    Rails.application.config.yml_data['common']
  end

  class Application < Rails::Application


    config.yml_data = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'platform', 'config.yml'))).result)

    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
  end
end
```

I have config.cache_classes set to false. Is there a way to reload MyApp ??? The config never gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you change things while the rails console is opened it will not automatically reload them. You have to use the command reload!

If it wasn’t what you are trying to do, please explain it with more detail.

Comment: reload! is the first command I tried. The problem is that application.rb does not change, the .yml file does.

Comment: I don`t know then. 

I know that scopes dont change the date.today if you dont use lambda, they get a date when the app starts and keep it. Maybe a lambda solve your problem.

I never used ylm files to config things. I'm too noob for that =D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your config file path to config.autoload_paths like its said on [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)